# Google Docs links don't work when embedded in Google Site as iframe

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites

I'm attempting to embed the "published to web" version of a Google doc as an iFrame inside a Google Sites page. My goal is for it to be "seamless" (i.e., the site's page viewer doesn't even know the source is a Google doc). It works visually, but there's a problem: links in the document don't work when clicked. You can right-click and open them in a new window or tab, and that works fine; it's just a regular click that doesn't work.

Here's an example of the iframe code that Sites creates. I pasted in the simple iframe embed code I got from:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/document/d/1FQ89vvRIvoatP9gLj6ZayYzLNbexyP00hDzLVbQ9Mfo/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

and it wrapped it in an iframe gadget:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Gadget'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D499'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Include+gadget+(iframe)%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D500'%3D1997'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D500'%3D1997'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=BakEflUXmCdkbXC00e3HHO70-n4" data-igsrc="http://106.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=106&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fa%2Fdocument%2Fd%2F1FQ89vvRIvoatP9gLj6ZayYzLNbexyP00hDzLVbQ9Mfo%2Fpub%3Fembedded%3Dtrue&amp;up_scroll=auto&amp;h=2000&amp;w=100%25" data-type="ggs-gadget" data-props="align:left;borderTitle:Include gadget (iframe);height:2000;igsrc:http#58//106.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=106&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fa%2Fdocument%2Fd%2F1FQ89vvRIvoatP9gLj6ZayYzLNbexyP00hDzLVbQ9Mfo%2Fpub%3Fembedded%3Dtrue&amp;up_scroll=auto&amp;h=2000&amp;w=100%25;mid:106;scrolling:no;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:null;spec:http#58//www.gstatic.com/sites-gadgets/iframe/iframe.xml;up_iframeURL:https#58//docs.google.com/a/salesforce.com/document/d/1FQ89vvRIvoatP9gLj6ZayYzLNbexyP00hDzLVbQ9Mfo/pub?embedded=true;up_scroll:auto;view:default;width:100%;" width="500" height="2000" style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;" class="igm">
```

(And, note this isn't the real doc; it's a "sites for your domain" page for my company that I've removed identifying info from.)